# itext7 - extracting PDF data, line segment locations and text locations do not seem to have same scale

Tags: .net, pdf, itext7

I am extracting the location of both lines and text in a PDF using iText7 and a modified extraction strategy.  No matter the extraction strategy the locations of line segments and texts do not appear to be on the same scale.

Here is the simplest extraction strategy, over-riding the LocationTextExtractionStrategy the line segment locations appear to be on a scale of about 2/3 that of the text locations.  Any suggestions as to what I am missing / doing wrong?:

```
    class LocationStrategyTextAndLines : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
    {
        public List<TextChunk> textChunkResult = new List<TextChunk>();
        public List<Line> lineResult = new List<Line>();
        
        public override void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
        {
            // get all line segments
            if (type.Equals(EventType.RENDER_PATH))
            {
                PathRenderInfo pRenderInfo = (PathRenderInfo)data;
                Path path = pRenderInfo.GetPath();
                path.ReplaceCloseWithLine();
                foreach (Subpath sPath in path.GetSubpaths())
                {
                    List<IShape> segments = (List<IShape>)sPath.GetSegments();
                    AddLines(segments);
                }
            }
            
            if (!type.Equals(EventType.RENDER_TEXT))
                return;
            
            // get text and text location info          
            TextRenderInfo renderInfo = (TextRenderInfo)data;
            Debug.WriteLine(renderInfo.GetText());
            string curFont = renderInfo.GetFont().GetFontProgram().ToString();
            float curFontSize = renderInfo.GetFontSize();

            TextChunk chunk = new TextChunk();
            chunk.text = renderInfo.GetText();

            Vector letterStart = renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
            Vector letterEnd = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
            float startX = Math.Min(letterStart.Get(0), letterEnd.Get(0));
            float startY = Math.Min(letterStart.Get(1), letterEnd.Get(1));

            Rectangle letterRect = new Rectangle(startX, startY, Math.Abs(letterEnd.Get(0) - letterStart.Get(0)), Math.Abs(letterEnd.Get(1) - letterStart.Get(1)));

            chunk.rect = letterRect;
            textChunkResult.Add(chunk);
            
        }
        
         private void AddLines(List<IShape> segments)
        {
            foreach (IShape segment in segments)
            {
                if (segment is Line) {
                lineResult.Add((Line)segment);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
        
    public class TextChunk
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public Rectangle rect { get; set; }

        public TextChunk()
        {
        }

        public TextChunk(string text, Rectangle rect)
        {
            this.text = text;
            this.rect = rect;
        }
    }
```

I have tried several methods of extracting the text and lines yet the results are always the same.  If it helps any, if I replot the data on a canvas of the page size it appears that text chunks are in the correct locations but the line segments appear correctly organized in relation to each other but at about 2/3 scale.

Answer (score 2):

I found what looks to be an X and Y scaling factor for line segments, I applied that and it appears to work correctly.

```
pathRenderInfo.GetGraphicsState().GetCtm();
```

Comment: Correct, the coordinates derived from the text already have the current transformation matrix applied while the coordinates of paths are raw and still need the ctm to be applied.